# Github using an unfamiliar .home email address when committing, rather than using my email

Tags: git, github

I'm committing to a project I just started on Github, and when I commit, the committer just has my first name and no profile picture. When I click the commit it asks me to confirm that I am myname@mynames-air.home. I have no idea why it's using that random .home email address for commits rather than the one that is associated with my Github account. And yes I've set my global email using `git config --global user.email myemail@gmail.com`, and my email is set as my primary email on Github.

Here is the result of 'git config -l --show-origin':

```
git config -l --show-origin
file:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig   credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/marina/.gitconfig   user.email=marinalunaterry@gmail.com
file:.git/config        core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config        core.filemode=true
file:.git/config        core.bare=false
file:.git/config        core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config        core.ignorecase=true
file:.git/config        core.precomposeunicode=true
file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=git@github.com:marinalunaterry/Ajax.git
file:.git/config        remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
file:.git/config        branch.master.remote=origin
file:.git/config        branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: And if you just run `git config user.email` within the repository? Do you still get the **myemail@gmail.com**?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git config -l --show-origin` and `env | grep '^GIT'`?

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne Yes, I get myemail@gmail.com.

Comment: @bk2204 I added the output of the git config command to the OP. env | grep '^GIT' outputs nothing.

Comment: What about `git log` does all of your commits show the same email?